Firebase Auth - Facebook token Error code 190
I am trying to sign in with Facebook on my Flutter app. I'm getting {"code":190,"message":"Bad signature"} as a response from Firebase_auth
According to FB developer docs 190 means "Access token has expired" and the solution is "Get A new access token"
Things I've tried:
Updating the firebase_auth package to 5.1.1
Regenerating the app secret
Disabling Facebook auth and reenabling on the firebase console
Deleting Facebook auth and recreating on the firebase console
Everything looks fine on the Facebook developer console. I did fail to submit my security checkup and it was enforced by facebook, but I've filled it out and am in good standing again. FWIW I am also seeing this message on the OAUTH screen, but I don't think that's related.
It seems like Firebase auth needs to get a new token from the facebook API - but I don't know how to force it to do taht if that's the case.
